# Query for select items where time after 12 O'clock

Tags: sql, oracle11g

[image: Table data]

Select all `VisitNo` between two days which are arrived after 12o’clock at noon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this,

```
SELECT VisitNo
FROM   <table_name>
WHERE  EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CAST(ArrivalDate AS TIMESTAMP)) >= 12;
```